# How/where does Redmine calculate/store Spent time?

Tags: redmine

I logged several time entries to an issue in project A, but they should have been logged to an issue in project B.

I tried using Redmine GUI to edit the time entries to be associated with the correct issue, but (because they're in different projects?) the edit was rejected with "invalid issue" or something.

So, I logged in to mysql and edited the log entries:

```
update time_entries set project_id=40, issue_id=2645 where `issue_id` = 2643;
```

Issue 2645 now correctly shows the logged time entries, and the total "Spent time"

Issue 2643 correctly does *not* show any time entries, but still shows the old value for "Spent time"

I tried refreshing the page, logging off and on, even using a new browser, but the value for Spent time persists in issue 2643.

I don't see a field named `spent_time` in TABLE `time_entries` or anything that looks similar when searching for the field name in DB `information_schema`.

```
select * from columns where (column_name like '%spent%' OR column_name LIKE '%time%') and table_schema = 'redmine';
```

How can I tell Redmine to update the value for "Spent time" after manually editing entries in TABLE `time_entries`?

Comment: It seems I confused myself because issue 2643 is the parent of 2645; *that's* why 2643 still shows the 'old' value for Spent Time.

Answer (score 1):

Time logging is quite tricky. You may have noticed that you cannot directly remove or reset a time logged. If you submit spent time, it will add to the previous spent hours. Also, like you mentioned, all the parent issues inherit the spent time from their subtasks.

A neat trick, if you write ".xml" at the end of your URL you will see some information about the issue. For example if you go to "localhost:8080/redmine/issue/500.xml", you will see a break down of the issue with id 500. This also applies to the group of issues.

Now, to see issue history, you can add ".xml?include=journals" to a desired issue link. This will show previous changes made and when they were made in an array format. Unfortunately this doesn't work with the group of issues, but there is a patch found at this link: http://www.redmine.org/issues/12746

There is also a gem called active resource. It allows you to write ruby scripts that can load issues as an object in xml format and you can edit, read, or add any issues or fields that you would like. This avoids using the database and can make things less risky.

**Useful link:**

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_ruby

Good luck!

-Josh

Comment: Thanks for these!  I can almost certainly remember to add .xml next time, so that's something I might do for fun!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, there's a way to do this through the Redmine GUI (given the correct level of access to the projects):

1. Change the project for one of the issues to the same project as the other issue.
2. Edit the time-spent entries to the other issue
3. Revert the project for the original issue changed above.

---

Your solution of making the change in mysql worked, though it can be risky if you're not careful.